# Relative Layout width/height is not work programmatically?

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to doing a relative layout programmatically and set android:layout_widht=60 android:layout_height=60.When i doing programmatically it is fill all screen? How can i do that?

my code:`

```
      RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rel_btn.height = 60;
        rel_btn.width = 60;
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
 this.setBackgroundResource(com.example.R.drawable.line);`
```

screen:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
btn.getLayoutParams().width = width;
btn.getLayoutParams().height = height;
```

in fact, just use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            60, 60);
```

that's OK. the problem maybe the background pic stretch the button